# Does the Goblin slayer anime series cover the whole manga/novels story?

Tags: goblin-slayer

I've just watched the Goblin Slayer anime series and it was pretty fun, I wonder, does it end there? Does the Goblin slayer anime series cover the whole manga/novels story or the story continues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://goblin-slayer.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Episodes):

- **Episodes 1 to 4**: Manga Chapters 1-9 and Light Novel Volume 1
- **Episode 5**: Manga Chapters 10 and 17, Light Novel Volumes 1, 2 and 4; and Goblin Slayer Brand New Day Chapter 1
- **Episodes 6 to 9**: Manga Chapters 17 to 29 and Light Novel Volume 2
- **Episodes 10 to 12**: Manga Chapters 10 to 15 and Light Novel Volume 1

The *Goblin Slayer* novel currently has 9 volumes, with 5 translated by Yen Press. The manga has 6 volumes with 4 translated by Yen Press. In addition, *Goblin Slayer: Side Story Year One* and *Goblin Slayer: Brand New Day* are not yet completely covered by the anime. With this, I think it's safe to say that **it does not end with the anime and that the story is still ongoing**.

Additional Sources:

- Goblin Slayer ([Novel](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=133022), [Manga](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=133340), [Brand New Day](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=148640), [Year One](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=144773))