# How many Goblin Slayer novel chapters are covered in manga?

Tags: goblin-slayer

How many Goblin Slayer novel is covered in manga

Comment: Partially answered on [Does the Goblin slayer anime series cover the whole manga/novels story?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/50344/2516)